# Can I create a Rails model where the ID auto-increments from 0, not 1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, auto-increment

Can I create a Rails model where the ID auto-increments from 0, not 1? How? Are there any gotchas? I checked here, and it seems I can't:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#M001911

If, as it seems, I cannot, is there reason why I can't or shouldn't just manually assign an ID of 0 to the first instance of this class? If I do, will Rails automatically assign an ID of 1 to the next instance created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord works on the principle that each table has a single primary key column that has no significance within the application domain. That's (partly) why you don't have to define the `id` column in your `create_table` migrations. The column name (and type) can be changed, largely to accommodate legacy schemas, and multiple-column primary keys are hard to implement at all.

At the point where you start to ascribe a domain significance to the id, you're starting to break the convention and I'd strongly advise that you create another field/property/member-variable/column/what-have-you to hold that information. Leave the id to being a key.

In the use-case you describe, there's no reason that your controller shouldn't identify the special case where `params[:id] == '0'` and deal with it appropriately, switching to the "project part", which you identify in some way other than by `id`. Since you probably want each project to start from 0, I'd guess you'd add something like `seq` and use that instead of `id` in your routes, that way your params keys make more sense. Keep the current highest `seq` value in the project, so it knows what number to assign when a new part is created. Deletions and insertions (assuming sequence matters) are entirely up to you...

Answer (score 5):

Why would you need to do that? In Rails model, the object id represents the unique id from database which never can be 0 (i speak for mysql, maybe there are exceptions with sequences and serials in postgres).

Comment: Thanks Eimantas. I was afraid of that.

You asked why I would need to do that? Because the model is "part", belongs_to "project". The first part as the part that encompasses the project as a whole. The software creates it when the user creates a project, before the user creates any smaller parts of their own. It would be nice from a UX perspective if this part appeared as "/part/0" to the user in the browser's location bar, and if the user only ever saw, say, "/part/2" if they had defined 2 parts of their own.

Comment: You could use separate counter for each part instead of using primary key for this.

Other than that i'd keep part 0 (for whole project) in the project object itself.

Comment: I speak for mysql, the default value for auto_increment column is 0, so the first record becomes 0 + 1 = 1, to get the "first record" value as 0 you will have to default the auto_increment value to -1 . So that -1 + 1 = 0  ,  I Doubt if that is going to be possible.

Comment: That would work only for the first project. When someone would create second project the 0-th part would be project1.parts.count + 1. And that not the thing you'd want.

Comment: Anand +1 for the default auto_increment tip. Didn't know that .)

Comment: You could redefine to_param in your model to return id - 1. Note that you will have to either redefine every find method you want to use of provide a convertion back from param to id in order to use finds.

Answer (score 0):

For postgres, you might wanna take a look at creating the table manually, e.g.

```
class MigrationName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    execute <<EOF

create sequence foos_id_seq start 0 increment 1 no cycle;
create table foos (
  id       integer not null default nextval('foos_id_seq'),
  ...
  primary key(id)
);
EOF
  end

  def self.down
    execute <<EOF
drop table foos;
drop sequence foos_id_seq;
EOF
  end
end
```

Note, the position of the EOF is important.